# Rails: Use environment variables defined with Figaro in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, figaro-ruby

If I'm not wrong, it seems like defined with Figaro variables are not available in Docker container.
I have `env` files to configure Postgresq DB:

`POSTGRES_USER=ENV['db_user']
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ENV['db_password]
POSTGRES_DB=ENV['db_name']`

I have `application.yml` file copied with all the other Rails app files to the container (I could check it with `ls` in the container shell).

Is it a normal behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue when working on a Rails application.

The thing to note here is that for **Docker**, environment variables are placed in a `.env` file or an `env_file` (`my_variables.env`). Environment files placed in `.yml` or `.yaml` files (`application.yml`) are not often recognized by Docker during runtime. Here's a link to Docker's official documentation that further explains it: [The “.env” file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

An example of such environment variables are **Database connection strings** which are required during the application startup process like:

```
database_name
database_username
database_password
```

However, you can still use the Figaro gem for defining variables that are not required during application startup, like:

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**